# How to fix "Debug Assertion Failed" "vector subscript out of range" in Adjacency List

Tags: c++, debugging, vector

I'm trying to implement a Adjacency List representation of a graph that calls values from a file, the first two numbers are the number of vertices and the number of edges, respectively. The next lines contain the endpoints of edges.

For example:

5 6

1 2

2 3

3 1

2 4

4 5

5 2

```
struct Edge {
    int src, dest;
};

class Graph
{
public:
    vector<vector<int>> adjList;
    Graph(vector<Edge> const &edges, int N)
    {
        adjList.resize(N);
        for (auto &edge : edges)
        {
            adjList[edge.src].push_back(edge.dest);
            //adjList[edge.dest].push_back(edge.src);
        }
    }
};
```

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int vertices;
    int num_edges;
    vector<Edge> edges;
    //string filename(argv[1]);
    string filename("graph5.data");

    ifstream readin;
    readin.open(filename);
    readin >> vertices >> num_edges;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_edges; i++) {
        int a, b;
        readin >> a >> b;
        edges.push_back({ a,b });
    }
    readin.close();

    Graph graph(edges, vertices);
    printGraph(graph, vertices);


    return 0;

}
```

I receive an error message along the lines of

"Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: C.....

Expression: vector subscript out of range"

and an exception is thrown at "adjList[edge.src].push_back(edge.dest);".

I believe there is a sizing error with my vectors, but I am unsure where and how to fix it.

Comment: In your data file, are the vertex numbers 0 based or 1 based?

Comment: You're trying to `push_back` to a vector of vectors and apparently the way you're doing it is incorrect.

Comment: From the error message, it's evident that `edge.src` is not a valid index for `adjList`. Use a debugger to see what it is, and why it is not between `0` and `N-1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a comment, but when you resize adjList to N(say 5 for now),it contains 5 vectors from adjList[0] to adjList[4].Now when you have an edge 5 2,your code tries to insert it into adjList[5],which doesn't exist.

So try changing

`adjList[edge.src].push_back(edge.dest)`

to

`adjList[edge.src-1].push_back(edge.dest)`

Comment: Looks like that was the whole problem. I thought it was something due to push_back. I had to change a few other things, but that got it compiling again. Thank you.